# Why does the syscall "process_vm_readv" sets errno to "success"?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, system-calls, ctypes

I am trying to implement a debugger in Python 3. The main idea is pretty simple: wrap the syscall "[process_vm_readv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html)" with ctypes and then call it on other process.

I also created a small dummy C++ program for me to debug with this tool. Here's the source for both of them:

---

### Debugger

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import typing
import ctypes
import os

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

def _error_checker(result, function, arguments):
    if result == -1:
        errno = ctypes.get_errno()
        raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))

class IOBuffer(ctypes.Structure): # iovec struct
    _fields_ = [("base", ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("size", ctypes.c_size_t)]

_read_process_memory = libc.process_vm_readv
_read_process_memory.restype = ctypes.c_ssize_t
_read_process_memory.errcheck = _error_checker
_read_process_memory.args = [ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.POINTER(IOBuffer),
                            ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.POINTER(IOBuffer),
                            ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong]

def read_process_memory(pid: int, base: int, size: int) -> typing.Tuple[int, bytes]:
    buffer = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
    local = IOBuffer(ctypes.addressof(buffer), size)
    remote = IOBuffer(base, size)
    return _read_process_memory(pid, local, 1, remote, 1, 0), buffer.raw
```

---

## Dummy Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int a = 99;
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        cout << "int a=" << a << ";\t&a=" << &a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

My problem lies in the fact that whenever I call "read_process_memory" with my dummy program's pid, the memory address it supplies me and the number 4 (the size of an `int`) as arguments - which should work - the wrapped syscall returns -1 (error). When that happens, `errcheck` reports the errno for that operation, which always ends up being zero. "Error Success". Due to this unhelpful error message I don't know how to fix this issue. Do you guys have any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897735/6276736), I ran my debugging tool with `strace -e process_vm_readv` prepended in the command line. It gave me the following error:

```
process_vm_readv(3464,
                 [{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0},
                  {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0},
                  {iov_base=0x7f9d39c0c4f8, iov_len=140313255527400},
                  {iov_base=0xfffffffffffffffa, iov_len=4}],
                 4, 0x1, 140726046508276, 4)
= -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

After fiddling around with the code for a bit, I got this error to be gone, by changing the `read_process_memory` function to:

```
def read_process_memory(pid: int, base: int, size: int) -> typing.Tuple[int, bytes]:
    buffer = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
    local = (IOBuffer * 1)()
    local[0].base, local[0].size = ctypes.addressof(buffer), size
    remote = (IOBuffer * 1)()
    remote[0].base, remote[0].size = base, size
    return _read_process_memory(pid, local, 1, remote, 1, 0), buffer.raw
```

My only problem now was that strace was throwing at me the following error:

```
process_vm_readv(3464,
                 [{iov_base=0x7fedc6f64450, iov_len=4}], 1,
                 [{iov_base=0x7ffd560344f4, iov_len=4}], 1, 0)
= -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

To which I responded by running it all as root, solving this last issue.

---

**Edit:** As suggested by Mark Tolonen, instead of declaring two arrays of size one in `read_process_memory`, both structures could be passed to the wrapped function using `ctypes.byref` as follows:

```
def read_process_memory(pid: int, base: int, size: int) -> typing.Tuple[int, bytes]:
    buffer = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
    local = IOBuffer(ctypes.addressof(buffer), size)
    remote = IOBuffer(base, size)
    return _read_process_memory(pid, ctypes.byref(local), 1, ctypes.byref(remote), 1, 0), buffer.raw
```

Comment: You might try your original code with `_read_process_memory(pid,ctypes.byref(local),1,ctypes.byref(remote),1,0)`.  You shouldn't have to declare an IOBuffer array of size 1.

Comment: Indeed that was the case. I'll edit my answer asap to reflect your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to this unhelpful error message I don't know how to fix this issue

You can *always* find out the *real* error returned by the kernel with [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). Something like this should work:

```
strace -e process_vm_readv python test.py
```